# How to factor 30 digit number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, contest-math

I need to find the prime factorization of a number having 30 digits.

I used the Pollard rho method but unfortunately it is not sufficient enough.

It needs a more advanced prime factorization process.
Please Help.

Comment: You refer to a problem in a set of online math challenges.  I don't know whether the file of test cases I'd get from the site would agree with the one you got.  Perhaps you should narrow your question a bit.

Comment: edit out the bit about SPOJ and just say you need to factor 30 digit numbers in <time> on average.

Comment: Okay, maybe have a look at these [*Prime Factorization Algorithms*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorizationAlgorithms.html) Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [applet](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) factorizes numbers using the elliptic curve method. It factors $30$ digit numbers almost instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) which can factor numbers of that size in a fraction of a second.